# Does AWS support Kubernetes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes

I've read that AWS does not support Kubernetes and builds their own Docker orchestration engine EC2 Container Service. However, on Kubernetes getting-started -page there is a guide on how to run Kubernetes on AWS:
    https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/getting-started-guides/aws.md

Which is right?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can install Kubernetes on a normal Amazon [EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) server.

The new container service is a separate offering by Amazon, called [ECS](http://aws.amazon.com/ecs/).

EDIT: AWS released in 2018 a new container service for Kubernetes called EKS: https://aws.amazon.com/eks/

> Amazon Elastic Container Service for Kubernetes (Amazon EKS) makes it easy to deploy, manage, and scale containerized applications using Kubernetes on AWS. Amazon EKS runs the Kubernetes management infrastructure for you across multiple AWS availability zones to eliminate a single point of failure.

Comment: can we run minikube on amazon linux ? I am getting issues : [ec2-user@ip-192-168-1-135 ~]$ minikube start --vm-driver kvm2
Starting local Kubernetes v1.10.0 cluster...
Starting VM...
E0503 12:38:37.812512    3987 start.go:159] Error starting host: Error creating new host: dial tcp: missing address.

 Retrying.
E0503 12:38:37.813474    3987 start.go:165] Error starting host:  Error creating new host: dial tcp: missing address

Comment: @AshishKarpe This is an old question now. AWS have no finally made available their managed k8s offering

https://aws.amazon.com/eks/

Answer (score 5):

Kubernetes provides scripts to simple setup a cluster on a set of EC2 machines. The setup does pretty much everything needed to get started quickly.

Here is the link: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/release-1.0/docs/getting-started-guides/aws.md

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible to setup Kubernetes on AWS See:http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/getting-started-guides/aws.html

1. You can also manually setup Kubernetes on AWS by launching a EC2 instance 
   Foe setting in Redhat ami https://access.redhat.com/articles/1353773
   (Note: Kubernetes needs flannel network to be setup for managing networking between docker containers running on different hosts(minions)

Answer (score 1):

Amazons Container Service is unrelated to Kubernetes.

There are 3 main options for installing Kubernetes on AWS:

1. CoreOS have a cli for installing and managing kubernetes on aws: https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/kubernetes-on-aws.html
2. Kubernetes have some scripts for setting up a cluster on AWS: http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/aws/
3. Manual installation on EC2. Lots of options here: http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/#cloud

As an aside minikube is now a thing which is nice for running locally to try stuff out:
http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/minikube/

Comment: Yep usually agree just hard with this as all these quick start guides require downloads and the instructions are quite regularly updated, and quite extensive, so hard to put them all in a Stackoverflow response

Answer (score 1):

AWS recently launched [EKS](https://aws.amazon.com/eks/), which provides a managed k8s master nodes. This should be 
what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use kubeadm to install kubernetes on EC2 instances.
There are other tools also available.

1. KOPS
2. EKS
3. Kubeadm